# Is it possible to set/change the Expiration Time of Workflow Activity Dynamically?

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

I have a requirement where I want to set the expiration time of the next activity or change the expiration time of that activity from my code dynamically. Is it possible ?

For Information: I am using Tridion 2013 sp1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented the code using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Workflow and there are 2 properties called -

1. `public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }` Under `ActivityData` class
2. `public DateTime? NextActivityDueDate { get; set; }` Under `ActivityFineshData` class

one can update the Expiration Time of an activity from code by set the value of DueDate property dynamically.

Using NextActivityDueDate also can control the expiration time from previous activity. Sample Code -

```
CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, new ActivityFinishData { Message = "Mail Sent to Target Audience, Finished Activity", NextActivityDueDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5) }, null);
```

But make sure that the **Allow to override due date**(refer below screenshot) check box is checked. Otherwise it will throw an error -

> DueDate property can't be updated manually, when it's restricted by activity definition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working code snippet but it looks possible using TOM .NET, with little modification, based on the following [online documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0A0CB9CD-CABE-4908-83F4-183F8A01BB37).

Comment: Thanks Shiva. I will try it out first and then get back to you.